# How can I rotate a 3D point about y-axis respect to the point C=(Cx, Cy, Cz)?

Tags: 3d, rotation, geometry, plane

For example, let's say I have P0 = (x, y, z) and I want to rotate it about y-axis with respect to the point C = (Cx, Cy, Cz)

I know that the rotation matrix to apply is:

{ {cos(angle),0,sin(angle),0}, {0,1,0,0}, {-sin(angle),0,cos(angle),0}, {0,0,0,1} }

But this matrix would be used in case of rotating with respect to (0,0,0), right?

How can I do it respect to a different point?

Comment: [Translate it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix), rotate it, translate it back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: P' = (P - C) * A + C]

where `P` is your point, `C` the point that should be the origin and `A` the transformation matrix.

Comment: 'A' would be the transformation matrix or the rotation matrix?

Comment: A rotation *is* a transformation. In this particular case its a rotation, but `A` can really be any kind of transformation. On a side note, translations á la `A + B` can also be expressed as a [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)).